# Magento billing address n/a field values - When Customer register but not having any address yet

Tags: magento, checkout, billing

I am getting problem on Magento checkout page. While customer is register, and not enter his/her address details in my account section and try to checkout then on billing screen getting fields with n/a values that should be empty. Only first name and last name should be there.

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with n/a values?

Comment: Getting n/a fields value. For example First Name: n/a, Last Name: n/a that should contains original values that customer give when register.

Comment: did you have a look into the database to check, wether they are filled? The question is: where are the values from

Comment: Yes. They are filled in backend.

Comment: then everything is correct in the checkout. The question now is, why is the database filled with the data? Did you import the data from somewhere and the fields are filled with n/a instead of NULL or ''?

Answer (score -1):

So you need to override the 
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\progress.phtml` nearly line 41 in below code.

```
<address><?php echo $this->getBilling()->format('html') ?></address>
```

for sidebar and in 
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml` for dropdown near line 34

```
<?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
```

Comment: NEVER NEVER EDIT ANY FILES IN app/design/frontend/base/default, app/design/adminhtml/default/default or app/code/code

Comment: my mistake thanks, I was trying to say override not to change in the core file.